# Google not updating title with htaccess expires

Tags: seo, htaccess, php

It's been 2 weeks I've changed my website title and still Google hasn't changed the title in search engine. I think it's because of if modified since header... my website is generating 201 OK status every time is there any solution?

Code for my htaccess

```
 <IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
 ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
 </IfModule>

 <ifModule mod_gzip.c>
 mod_gzip_on Yes
 mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
 mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
 mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
 mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
 mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
 mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
 mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
 </ifModule>
```

If anyone could tell me how to use it with php that could be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can decrease expiration of your php to 1 week
and remove cache on PHP

```
# EXPIRE HEADERS
ExpiresActive On
#Images
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
AddType image/x-icon .ico
ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
#Elements
ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
#Others
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"


# CACHE-CONTROL HEADERS
# Disable caching for scripts and other dynamic files
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Sat, 2 Aug 1980 15:15:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
 mod_gzip_on Yes
 mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
 mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
 mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
 mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
 mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
 mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
 mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
 </ifModule>
```